# GoogleTest building with android NDK (r13b) giving error (C++ headers not found)

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, googletest

I was trying to build GoogleTest with Android NDK but it's getting error , couldn't find c++ headers properly on gTest sources (like- 'limits'/'ostream'/'vector'... file not found , please see given error file). What could be the problem? Your valuable suggestion would be helpful.

### Error given by Android Studio

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : foo <= foo.cpp
make: Entering directory `/media/user/New Volume/Android_live_streaming_test_client/AndroidNDKDemo/app/src/main'
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libfoo.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libfoo.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : foo_unittest <= foo_unittest.cpp
Error:(54, 10) 'limits' file not found
/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/foo_unittest/foo_unittest.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/media/user/New Volume/Android_live_streaming_test_client/AndroidNDKDemo/app/src/main'
:app:ndkBuild FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

---

**Android.mk file**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo_unittest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo_unittest.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := googletest_main
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(call import-module,third_party/googletest)
```

---

**Application.mk file**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

---

Gradle file, from where the ndk-build command has been called

```
    import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ipvcloud.androidndkdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine android.ndkDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + '/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'


    // 'command '/home/jumman/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
}
```

Comment: You've just read my mind.. I am facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Works for me when using ndk-build directly. Maybe file a bug against gradle at b.android.com?